# How to call WebMethod accepting Collection datatype as input

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a .net Web method as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public void UpdateDataBase(List<string> values)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=******; password=*******; server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=************;");
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "Insert into TestWeb(Test1,Test2,Test3) values(values[0],values[1],values[2])";
    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

From an excel add-in I create a reference to the Web Service class that has this method and use the following to call it.

```
private void Test()
{
    ServiceReference1.SNLSoapClient svr = new ServiceReference1.SNLSoapClient();
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    values.Add("Test1");
    values.Add("Test2");
    values.Add("Test3");
    svr.UpdateDataBase(values);
}
```

But I get an error on the last line saying the Web method accepts only a string array as input and not a List which is not right as you could see in the Web method definition? What should be done to enable the passing of collection types to Web methods?

Comment: Web methods accept collection objects as arguments. i test it. which .net version u used?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't add your list values to your `SqlCommand` in your `UpdateDataBase` method.

You might need something like;

```
[WebMethod]
public void UpdateDataBase(List<string> values)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=******; password=*******; server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=************;");
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "Insert into TestWeb(Test1,Test2,Test3) values(@p0,@p1,@p2)";
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", values[0]);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", values[1]);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", values[2]);
    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: No. But I get a compile-time error that my Web method accepts only a string array and not a list of strings, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Sai What is your Web method? Is it `UpdateDataBase`? Because it is not accept a string array, it accepts `List<string>` which I assume it is not.

Comment: Yes. `UpdateDatabase()` is the Web method.(it accepts a `List` and I am passing only a `list`). Question updated to reflect this.